# Why isn't C freeing memory from malloc'd char* set by strtok?

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, free

This function reads the values from a text file with space separated values, into a 2d array. When I run it, works just fine - but a memory leak check through Valgrind confirms Xcode's suspicions that "char *splitString" is never freed, the two times which it is called. I don't understand this, considering my "char *buffer" seems to be freed just fine. Any help is super appreciated!

```
int** readMatrixFile(char* inFileName, int** matrix, int sizeY, int sizeX)
{
    FILE* matrixFP;
    int ii=0, jj=0, fileValid = 1;
    char *buffer, *splitString;
    const char delim[]=" \n\r";

    matrixFP = fopen(inFileName, "r");
    if(matrixFP != NULL)
    {
        /*Check if file is the same size as specified by the command line
         *assumed valid until the file is checked*/
        splitString = malloc(100*sizeof(char)); <------where allocated
        buffer = malloc(5000*sizeof(char));
        do
        {
            fgets(buffer, 5000, matrixFP);
            jj=0;
            splitString = strtok(buffer, delim);
            while(splitString != NULL)
            {
                jj++;
                splitString = strtok(NULL, delim);
            }
            if(jj!=sizeX)
            {
                fileValid = 0;
            }
            ii++;
        } while(!feof(matrixFP));
        if(ii != sizeY || buffer==NULL)
        {
            fileValid = 0;
        }

        free(splitString); <-----Appears to do nothing?
        free(buffer);

        if(fileValid) /*Files match to specified command line values*/
        {
            ii=0;
            rewind(matrixFP);
            matrix = (int**)malloc(sizeY * sizeof(int *));
            do
            {
                matrix[ii] = (int*)malloc(sizeX * sizeof(int));
                jj=0;
                do
                {
                    fscanf(matrixFP, "%d", &matrix[ii][jj]);
                    jj++;
                } while(jj<sizeX);
                ii++;
            } while(ii<sizeY && !feof(matrixFP));
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error: File does not match size specified by the command line\n");
        }
        fclose(matrixFP);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Error: File does not exist or is invalid");
        matrix = NULL;
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

**And Valgrind output:**

```
==14087== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14087== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14087== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14087== Command: ./pmms a b 10 3 10
==14087== 
/*irrelevent program output*/ 
==14087== 
==14087== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14087==     in use at exit: 200 bytes in 2 blocks
==14087==   total heap usage: 21 allocs, 19 frees, 11,680 bytes allocated
==14087== 
==14087== 100 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==14087==    at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==14087==    by 0x400B55: readMatrixFile (matrix_reader.c:35)
==14087==    by 0x40095E: main (pmms.c:23)
==14087== 
==14087== 100 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==14087==    at 0x4A06A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==14087==    by 0x400B55: readMatrixFile (matrix_reader.c:35)
==14087==    by 0x400982: main (pmms.c:24)
==14087== 
==14087== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14087==    definitely lost: 200 bytes in 2 blocks
==14087==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14087==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14087==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14087==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14087== 
==14087== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14087== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: There is no 2D array in the code, and nothing which can be used as one.

Comment: And don*t cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you iterate

```
    while(splitString != NULL)
    {
          ...
    }
```

so after the loop completion `splitString` is `NULL`, and `free(NULL)` does nothing.

Second, once you allocated a hundred-byte memory block

```
    splitString = malloc(100*sizeof(char));   // (*)
```

the next reference to the `splitString` variable is an assignment:

```
    splitString = strtok(buffer, delim);
```

So, whatever was stored in the variable, it got overwritten! `splitString` points somewhere into the `buffer` block now and the address of the block allocated at `(*)` is lost forever. That, by the way, indicates you never use that block, and you don't actually need to allocate it.

Comment: _"you never use that block, and you don't actually need to allocate it"_ +1

Comment: Legend! I see what you mean, considering the address for splitString then would get changed wherever inside "buffer" the first time strtok is called. First time using stackoverflow, impressed 

Answer (score 5):

You change the value of `splitString` here:

```
            splitString = strtok(NULL, delim);
```

and here:

```
            splitString = strtok(buffer, delim);
```

so it no longer points to the memory block to be freed, so the `free()` will do nothing, as by the time this line is reached, `splitString` will be `NULL`, and `free(NULL)` is defined to do nothing.

Comment: _"so the `free()` does nothing"_ No, calling `free()` invokes undefined behavior. Unless the argument is null, then it does nothing.

Comment: freeing a NULL pointer is not undefined behaviour. As per the standard, if you pass a null pointer, nothing happens

Comment: @AbhinavUpadhyay indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `while(splitSring != NULL)` loop you are using `strtok(3)` which modifies it. At the end of the loop `splitString` will be `NULL` and essentially you are calling `free(NULL)`, while leaking the originally allocated memory.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to your question, just a suggestion that may help to avoid the problem altogether:

When using `strtok()` and family, you do not need to explicitly allocate memory for the object you are using to capture the return value:

```
char delim[] = {" \n\t"};  //or whatever delimitors you need
char *tok = NULL;

tok = strtok(stringToParse, delim);  
while(tok)
{
    //do something with tok
    ...
    //get next token:
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
}
```

And, there is no need to free `tok` when used as shown.